# Using ffserver to do UDP multicast streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, multicast, ffserver

Here's the deal. I'm working with IPTV hardware and I need to output a bunch of demo streams. These are MPEG2 transport stream that need to be straight up UDP Multicast streams. I have an ffmpeg command that works great:

`ffmpeg -re -i /Volumes/Data/DemoVideos/GRAILrpsp.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mpegts udp://239.192.1.82:12000[ttl=1,buffer_size=2097157]`

What I would like to do is convert this into an ffserver config file instead of having to start a whole bunch of ffmpeg streams and then figuring out how to get them to loop. I'm sure I can do it with the right scripting but what a pain, isn't that what ffserver is for? But I can't find any documentation on doing UDP streaming using ffserver. You can set a multicast address and port but it goes to RTP which this hardware isn't designed for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this post, according to the [ffserver Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html) it doesn't support `MPEG-TS` directly in `UDP`:

> `ffserver` receives prerecorded files or FFM streams from some `ffmpeg`instance as input, then streams them over **RTP/RTSP/HTTP**.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had read all the documentation but clearly missed that line.